# scheme filter function code meaning

Tags: scheme

I am asked to interpret the following code:

```
(define (filter p l)
   (cond 
      ((null? l) ’())
      (#t (let ((result (filter p (cdr l))))
          (if (p (car l)) 
              (cons (car l) result) 
              result)))))
```

and the solution is "`filter` returns elements `e` in `l` where `(p e)` is `#t`"
but I am not really sure what the 3rd line is doing. is the `#t` saying we always accept this condition? Also how is the 'let' working in this case?

Comment: use standard indentation - break up your expressions and put each subexpression on its own line, that it will become clear.  -- #t case: yes, it is true, so it succeeds and clause is executed - unless a clause above it was chosen.

Comment: @WillNess thanks! that did make it more clear.

Comment: @WillNess If that's the case, when editing the question, in addition to reverting the code to be misformatted, it might also make sense to edit it to also ask about proper formatting so that the answer makes sense.

Comment: @benrudgers I am probably missing something here, so I'll defer to your judgement and undo the rollback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's formatted a bit weird, but cond here is functioning as a match expression from haskell or ML like this:

```
match l with
| [] -> []
| x :: xs -> 
    let result = filter p xs in
    (if p x then 
        x :: result
     else
        result
    )
```

Cond takes pairs of (execute-this? to-execute), so it should read more like this

```
(cond 
   ((null? l)  ’())
   (#t         (let ((result (filter p (cdr l))))
                 (if (p (car l)) 
                   (cons (car l) result) ;; then
                   result) ;; else
               )))
```

So #t -> do this other stuff is the default case because it always executes if the list wasn't empty, which would trigger (null? l).  Therefore it has to be last.